# i/o timeout when trying to renew letsencrypt certificate

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, https, lets-encrypt, caddy

I am running a webserver using caddy 1, which is supposed to renew https certificates automatically using letsencrypt but is having trouble doing so. In the server's logs I see this:

```
2022/01/14 04:03:47 [ERROR] Making new certificate manager: get directory at 'https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory': Get https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory: dial tcp: lookup acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org on 10.6.30.9:53: read udp 10.67.6.77:39492->10.6.30.9:53: i/o timeout (attempt 1/3)
```

I'm not sure where to go from here and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a simple dns error. I added `nameserver 1.1.1.1` to the bottom of my `/etc/resolv.conf` file and restarted caddy. Working like a charm.